# Why does await Task take considerably longer than return Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have made an interesting observation which I would like to fully understand.

The easiest way to explain this is by capturing it with this little sample console application:

```
namespace AsyncAwaitTestApp
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var timer = new Stopwatch();

            // First Run:
            // -------------------------

            Console.WriteLine("Running GiveMeATask in parallel...");
            timer.Start();

            Parallel.For(0, 500, (i) =>
            {
                SillyClass.GiveMeATask().Wait();
            });

            timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"GiveMeATask run completed. Total time: {timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} seconds.");

            // Second Run:
            // -------------------------

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Running AwaitATask in parallel...");
            timer.Restart();

            Parallel.For(0, 500, (i) =>
            {
                SillyClass.AwaitATask().Wait();
            });

            timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"AwaitATask run completed. Total time: {timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} seconds.");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class SillyClass
    {
        public static TimeSpan SomeTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

        public static Task GiveMeATask()
        {
            return Task.Delay(SomeTime);
        }

        public static async Task AwaitATask()
        {
            await Task.Delay(SomeTime);
        }
    }
}
```

It is also available as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/dustinmoris/4533a99be1912b8ca9ff).

`SillyClass` has two methods which both return a `Task`. Inside both methods I have a `Task.Delay` of 3 seconds to simulate an expensive network or IO bound operation.

The first method `GiveMeATask` simply returns the task from `Task.Delay`. The second method `AwaitATask` awaits the `Task.Delay` with the `async`/`await` keywords.

Both methods get called from `Parallel.For` to simulate concurrent calls.

What I found interesting is that the first run always takes about double the time as the second run, no matter how many times I repeat it:

[image: Output from console application]

As far as I understand the `async`/`await` pattern has to capture a synchronisation context, which adds a little bit of overhead, but I would be surprised if that is the reason?

I also understand that in certain applications such as a WPF application or an ASP.NET application where only 1 thread can access the UI/Request context an synchronously blocking `.Wait()` can cause deadlocks, but this is not the case for console applications and evidently I don't have a deadlock here, because both runs complete just fine.

So I am clearly not understanding the full picture of the above and would appreciate someone who can shed more light on this?

Comment: When [microbenchmarking](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/benchmark.html), be sure to do proper warmups first.

Comment: @StephenCleary Okay, let me read the linked blog post and I will see if that changes my results. Thanks.

Comment: @shay__ Ops, yes its the other way around. I will update the question.

Comment: I'd also set `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads/SetMinThreads` to the same (reasonably large) number, at the very beginning.

Comment: @StephenCleary The `Benchmarking.cs` seems to have an error. It retrieves all types by calling `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetTypes()` which doesn't pick up my class with the public static methods which have been decorated with the `Benchmark` attribute. I think it should be `.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()` instead. Anyway, I don't see there any code which would do a warm up. What would you suggest? Just run my code a couple times in a row?

Comment: @dustinmoris: Yes. Also use Noseratio's advice. There are lots of potential problems with microbenchmarking.

Comment: @dustinmoris: From the page: "Once you've downloaded it, using it is simple: just compile it into the same assembly as the code you wish to benchmark, and run it." At that point, there's only one assembly anyway. That said, that page was written years and years ago. These days I'd suggest https://github.com/PerfDotNet/BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: @JonSkeet Makes sense. Thanks for the super swift responses by the way! I will try all your suggestions and see where it takes me. Just by the sound of what I described in my initial question, does that make any sense to you or am I doing something silly here and wasting my time?

Comment: @dustinmoris I don't know why, but the second `Paraller.For` executes much faster than the first one. **Even** if you exchange the bodies or use one and the same body. But for sure it's unrelated to `Task` and `await`.

Comment: @dustinmoris: I suspect the slowdown on the first test is due to the limited rate of thread pool thread injection. Noseratio's comment should remove that.

Comment: Applying your suggestions resulted in no differences between the two runs anymore. Thanks everyone for pointing me into the right direction!